# Selenium automation running only in XP inside sauce lbs

Tags: java, selenium, saucelabs

Am new to selenium automation.Am trying to run selenium scripts inside sauce labs (Selenium version 2.44)

The tests are running succesfully in sauce labs

But the problem is i set the capability as Platform.WIN_8 .But inside sauce labs it is running in Windows XP with browser firefox.
Why it is happening like this.Also i faced the same issue when i tired in linux or mac also.In sauce labs automation running only in XP if i selected any other platforms like VISTA Win7 Vista

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {       
        capabillities.setCapability("version", "5.0");
        capabillities.setCapability("platform", Platform.WIN_8);
         capabillities.setCapability("browser", "firefox");
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                      new URL("http://name:key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
                      capabillities);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could assume that the problem hides into the Platform.WIN_8.
Try to use caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 8");
Here is a [configurator](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/#/) which could help you to create caps for a correct configuration